# jQuery cookie if statement

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, hide

Here's my script & I just want the 'disableAutoPlay' div to be hidden if the user has the cookies 'AutoPlayTrue' & 'AutoPlayFalse'.
This is my current script & the bottom part is where I'm attempting to hide 'disableAutoPlay' if the user has the above cookies.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#yes a').click(function() {
        $.cookie('AutoPlayFalse', null);
        $.cookie('AutoPlayTrue', '1', {
            expires: 9999
        });
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide('slow');
        $.cookie('ccss_remembered_style', null);
    });
    $('#ccss-no a').click(function() {
        $.cookie('AutoPlayTrue', null);
        $.cookie('AutoPlayFalse', '1', {
            expires: 9999
        });
        $('.disableAutoPlay').hide('slow');
    });
    $('#autoPlayOptions a').click(function() {
    $('.displayAutoPlay').css('display','block !important');
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayFalse') == "1") {
        $('.displayAutoPlay').hide();
    }
    if ($.cookie('AutoPlayTrue') == "1") {
        $('.displayAutoPlay').hide();
    }
});
</script>

<li class="widget ccss" id="ccss-widget-3"><h2 class="widgettitle">Should HipHop97.com Automatically Start Playing Music?</h2>
    <ul id="ccss-list">

        <li id="ccss-no"><a href="http://hiphop97.com/wp-content/themes/hiphop/noAutoPlayCSS.css">No</a></li><li id="yes"><a href="#">Yes</a></li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: and you do realize your calling `.hide()` on displayAutoPlay no matter what your cookie value is, right?

Comment: Well the element is still showing up; how can I display it as hidden if the cookie exists?

Comment: what does `alert($.cookie("AutoPlayFalse"))` give?

Comment: What do you mean 'alert($.cookie("AutoPlayFalse"))' what does that function do?

Comment: it'll show you an alert box with the value of the AutoPlayFalse cookie. I'm just wondering what exactly is the value of those cookies.

Comment: i don't see anything in your html with the class displayAutoPlay

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're  setting 
`('.displayAutoPlay').css('display','block !important');` 
which means any attempt to hide the element from jQuery may fail. Try removing the !important.

Comment: all that function does is display the disableAutoPlay true on click, nothing more. But I did test it and remove the !important (that didn't work) and I also tried setting it to:     $('#autoPlayOptions a').click(function() {
 $('.displayAutoPlay').show();
    });

Comment: @Stephen okay, can you post your HTML?

Comment: I added the HTML at the bottom of the code tag in my main question.